Validity of exceptions in GPLv2 software combinations
Let's say library P is licensed under GPLv2 with the GCC Runtime Library Exception 2.0 or another similar exception like the Classpath Exception.
Proprietary software K uses library P. This is allowed by the exception. I can distribute K with P.
Now let's say library P is modified by a licensee to use library Q which is licensed under GPLv2 with no exceptions. Let's call this derivative, P2.
Can I link K with P2 and Q and distribute them together? Does the exception apply to the combination of P2 + Q?
You can assume that K, P2 and Q are linked in such a way that K depends on P2 and P2 depends on Q. K does not depend directly on Q.
You can also assume that K, P2 and Q are all written completely in the C language.

No, the exception cannot apply to the combination of both licenses.
A project can choose a license freely when all participants (copyright holder) agree. Combining it with a 3rd - party library binds you to completely fulfill the license conditions by that 3rd-party library. That holds true whether what I distribute is a single combined library, or a executable programme - from a copyright POV that is no difference.
The situation you describe is called "transitive license dependency", thus the fact that A depends on B depends on C. Thus the distribution license of B has to fulfill all conditions of C. And consequently the distribution license of A has to fulfill all conditions of B and by induction also all those of C. Thus if C is licensed GPL without any exception, then the distribution of B can also be only as GPL without any exceptions which means that any programme A which includs B has also to comply with GPL without any exceptions (and that definitely excludes any proprietary programme).
See also this related question and answer on this kind of scenario.
